# How to copy datastore entities between namespaces

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I want to copy all the data in one namespace, say www.mysite.com, to another namespace, say nightly.latest.mysite.appspot.com. What's the best way to do this?

The example namespaces are not random: they're the namespaces that are set by a NamespaceFilter for the given domains that serve the app.

I want to be able to pull all the 'production' data into a 'non-production' namespace for testing.

Comment: Do you think that the remote access API can help you in this endeavor? It requires you to download the python SDK but you can set it up to work for your java application. I just happened to read this chapter in "Programming Google App Engine" yesterday, about bulk data operations and remote access: http://my.safaribooksonline.com/web-development/9780596157517/bulk-data-operations-and-remote-access/using_the_remote_api_from_a_script#X2ludGVybmFsX0ZsYXNoUmVhZGVyP3htbGlkPTk3ODA1OTYxNTc1MTcvMjc3

Comment: yeah, my assumption is the remote_api and its bulk data operations will have to be used, I just don't know how and don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: If you want to go the bulk loader approach, you'll need to upload a Python instance of your app too.  Docs are here:  http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata.html

Comment: @Robert Do I really need to upload the python sdk? "Tip: If you have a Java app, you can use the Python appcfg.py tool by installing the Java version of the remote_api handler, which is included with the Java runtime environment. The handler servlet class is com.google.apphosting.utils.remoteapi.RemoteApiServlet."

Comment: sorry about that.  You don't need to upload a Python version anymore.  But you still use the Python tools on the client side.  If you are doing this within the same app between namespaces, you might want to consider my answer to the question.  It will avoid having to download then re-upload all of your data (which will likely be significantly faster).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is currently no automated way to do this.

You are going to have to loop over all of your data and re-save it to the new namespace.  You can read about Java and namespaces, in the [multitenancy](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/multitenancy/multitenancy.html#Using_Namespaces_with_the_Datastore) docs.

Comment: I'm sure I'm going to have timeout issues with this approach, so this is non-trivial, which makes me hesitant to go this route.

Comment: You are going to need to use query cursors and the task-queue for this, like many other tasks on App Engine.

Comment: yeah. this is starting to feel like a full-fledged project of its own.

Comment: I think I'm going to try to use the mapreduce api for this.

Comment: As I found this question today by googling I wanted to say that now, 8 years later, there still doesn't seem to be an automated way, but you should be able to use Google Dataflow / ApacheBeam and load all Entities of a namespace, get their builders, replace the key (or only the namespace) and resave them, without the trouble of using taskQueues etc.

Answer (score 6):

Namespace is the part of the Key. So you can't change or copy all data from one namespace to another. As I understand all you can do is to fetch all objects from one namespace and create NEW objects with the same properties in another namespace.

Answer (score 4):

I'm using [appengine-mapreduce](http://code.google.com/p/appengine-mapreduce/) for this. I won't walk through setting it up in detail. You can read the [getting started guides](http://code.google.com/p/appengine-mapreduce/wiki/GettingStartedInJava) for that information.

Right now you have to enter each class name to be copied. TODO is figuring out how to loop over all the [__Stat_Kind__](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/stats.html) results programmatically so each kind/class doesn't have to be specified separately.

```
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable;

import com.google.appengine.api.NamespaceManager;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreService;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreServiceFactory;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Entity;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.KeyFactory;
import com.google.appengine.tools.mapreduce.AppEngineMapper;

public class DatastoreCopyMapper extends
        AppEngineMapper<Key, Entity, NullWritable, NullWritable> {

    private static final Logger log = Logger
            .getLogger(DatastoreCopyMapper.class.getName());
    private static String destination;

    public DatastoreCopyMapper() {
    }

    @Override
    public void taskSetup(Context context) {
        log.warning("Doing per-task setup");
        destination = context.getConfiguration().get("destination");
        log.warning("destination: " + destination);
    }

    @Override
    public void map(Key key, Entity value, Context context) {

        NamespaceManager.set(destination);
        String name = key.getName();
        long id = key.getId();
        Key destinationKey = null;
        if (name != null) {
            destinationKey = KeyFactory.createKey(key.getKind(), name);
        } else if (id != 0) {
            destinationKey = KeyFactory.createKey(key.getKind(), id);
        }
        Entity destinationEntity = new Entity(destinationKey);
        destinationEntity.setPropertiesFrom(value);
        DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory
                .getDatastoreService();

        datastore.put(destinationEntity);

    }
}
```

mapreduce.xml

```
<configurations>
  <configuration name="Copy between namespaces">
    <property>
      <name>mapreduce.map.class</name>
      <value>com.mysite.server.DatastoreCopyMapper</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>mapreduce.inputformat.class</name>
      <value>com.google.appengine.tools.mapreduce.DatastoreInputFormat</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name human="Entity Kind to Map Over">mapreduce.mapper.inputformat.datastoreinputformat.entitykind</name>
      <value template="optional">User</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name human="Destination Namespace">mapreduce.mapper.inputformat.datastoreinputformat.destination</name>
      <value template="optional">dev.mysite.com</value>
    </property>

  </configuration>
</configurations>
```