# Copy datastore entries between namespaces with objectify

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I have several namespaces and I'd like to copy data from one namespace to another with objectify. 
This question is to some extend similar to [How to copy datastore entities between namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4211605/how-to-copy-datastore-entities-between-namespaces). I'd like to implement this feature with objectify if possible.

Comment: The solution is the same as this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4211884/248432

Comment: So after all this years, no new solution has come up? I find this rather suprising... )-: I mean, shouldn't this be a common case? Copy data from one namespace to another? Especally with objectify since this framework is recommended from google itself.

Comment: Namespace is part of the key of every entity. To "copy between namespaces" one has to 1. create new entity with a key with new namespace 2. copy all properties between entities, 3. delete original entity.

Comment: Why should this be common case? I never had this use case. You can write a simple mapreduce job to do this

Comment: @marcadian I imagine that most application need some sort of schooling how to use the application. In this it would be nice if the user could work on the live data without actually work on the live data set. Or simple for test purposes.

Comment: @marcadian If you say mapreduce job, you mean this framework: https://code.google.com/p/appengine-mapreduce/ It would be nice, if there would be support/util code without introducing another "big" library.

Comment: Well, if you want to use it for testing, you should not use production server, use another server as test server and copy the data or create some fake data instead of isolating prod/test using namespace. Of course you can do that, you already have taskqueue and urlfetch, just execute a task to map entity to other namespace. In fact, mapreduce itself is built on top of the taskqueue :)